# How to test a function in a catch block of try/catch?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a custom package that is called if an error is thrown in the catch block of a try/catch. I want to test that the logFunction.error function is called. How do I test this function in the catch block? I'm passing in a mock jwt. I'm using jwtDcode (https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode) to decode my jwt. If it fails, an error is thrown the logFunction.error() returns a details object. Is this the correct way to set up this unit test?

**file.js**

```
jwtFunction ({commit}, idToken) {
 try {
   jwtDecode(idToken)
   // do some logic
 }catch (error) {
    logFunction.error({
      details: {
        event: 'invalid jwt'
        message: `${error.message} of ${idToken}`
        timeStamp: Date.now()
      }
   })
  commit(types.setApplicationError, error)
}
```

**file.spec.js**

```
it('[positive] should commit application error if jwt fails to decode', () => {
        const mockIdToken = {}
        const spy = jest.spyOn(logFunction, 'error')

        actions.jwtFunction({ commit }, mockIdToken)
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled()
      })
```

Comment: Are you trying to test if the third party package correctly throws an error when given bad input? I personally think might be too much for your unit tests. I'd recommend just directly testing the code you have direct control over, i.e. `logFunction.error`. And if you want to test the branches of `jwtFunction` you could mock the `jwtDecode` function and have it explicitly return an error rather than relying on the package itself to return the error.

Comment: Ok, so I thing I am on the right track spying on `logFunction.error()`. I understand what you mean by only testing the code you have control over. Yes I would like to test jwtDecode. By mocking the **jwtDecode** function, I can't use spyOn, how exactly do I do it? `const jwtDecode = jest.fn()`?

Comment: This page might help you https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks